# Using rvest functions on a dataframe column

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a large dataframe, called 'output', of which one column is html, called 'raw'.

I am trying to make a new column, style_col, which takes the style attribute of any element which has it. Here is my attempt:

```
style_col <- output %>% 
  mutate(style = read_html(raw) 
         %>% html_node('[style]') 
         %>% html_attr('style'))
```

The part that extracts style from HTML works on a single piece of HTML, but I can't seem to get the syntax right for operating on a dataframe. What is the correct way of doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
style_col <- output %>% 
  rowwise() %>% # I added this part
  # changed the formatting only here
  mutate(
    style = read_html(raw) %>%
      html_node('[style]') %>%
      html_attr('style')
    )
```